# assigning values to multiple objects in a for loop

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, while-loop

I have a bit of code in my project which reads data from a database and assigns it to the text on buttons. There are 25 buttons in a grid pattern in the program. The current solution is messy and has issues with empty data.

This is the current solution:

```
    rs.Read()
    Productbutton1.Text = (rs(0))
    rs.Read()
    Productbutton2.Text = (rs(0))
    rs.Read()
    Productbutton3.Text = (rs(0))
    rs.Read()
    Productbutton4.Text = (rs(0))
    rs.Read()
    Productbutton5.Text = (rs(0))
    rs.Read()
    Productbutton6.Text = (rs(0))
    rs.Read()
    Productbutton7.Text = (rs(0))
    rs.Read()
    Productbutton8.Text = (rs(0))
    rs.Read()
    Productbutton9.Text = (rs(0))
    rs.Read()
    Productbutton10.Text = (rs(0))
    rs.Read()
    Productbutton11.Text = (rs(0))
    rs.Read()
    Productbutton12.Text = (rs(0))
    rs.Read()
    Productbutton13.Text = (rs(0))
    rs.Read()
    Productbutton14.Text = (rs(0))
    rs.Read()
    Productbutton15.Text = (rs(0))
    rs.Read()
    Productbutton16.Text = (rs(0))
    rs.Read()
    Productbutton17.Text = (rs(0))
    rs.Read()
    Productbutton18.Text = (rs(0))
    rs.Read()
    Productbutton19.Text = (rs(0))
    rs.Read()
    Productbutton20.Text = (rs(0))
    rs.Read()
    Productbutton21.Text = (rs(0))
    rs.Read()
    Productbutton22.Text = (rs(0))
    rs.Read()
    Productbutton23.Text = (rs(0))
    rs.Read()
    Productbutton24.Text = (rs(0))
    rs.Read()
    Productbutton25.Text = (rs(0))
```

The problem I am facing is that I can't use a for loop in the sense:

```
    For i = 1 To 25
        rs.Read()
        Productbutton(i).text = (rs(0))
    Next
```

Because Visual basic wont allow me to substitute part of the button name for a variable. I have been told a while loop could be implemented as so: (`while rs.Read = true`). However I don't know how to progress through all of the button names in a while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the DirectCast to Cast Text into a button

```
For i = 1 To 25
    rs.Read()
    dim newButton = DirectCast(Controls("Productbutton" & i.ToString()), Button)
    newButton.text = (rs(0))
Next
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are using VB.NET and assuming `Productbutton[1-25]` always exist, you can do this:

```
For i = 1 To 25
    rs.Read()
    ' Locate the button with the name on the form.
    Dim btn As Button = Me.Controls.Find("Productbutton" & i, True)
    btn.Text = rs(0)
Next
```

Comment: I corrected the tags on the question, so I also removed the commentary about them from your answer.

Comment: There are other ways to do this google .net find control. For instance if these controls were in their own container e.a panel you could just do a foreach on MyPanel.Controls.